# span word-wrap in list elements

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am trying to have multiple `span` elements in a list item. They are suppose to be `inline` of course. When i add the `word-wrap: break-word` property to one of the `span` elements, i am expecting the words to wrap, but the element also wrap.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qntkhjdd/) you can clearly see that the `span` element with class `message` is behind the element `name`. I would like these elements inline but with a word wrapping for the second with class `message`.

What I am trying to achive could be compared to twitch.tv chat messages structure.
[image]

The twitch.tv HTML for a message is the following:

```
<li class="ember-view message-line chat-line" id="ember6565">
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <span class="timestamp float-left">3:34</span> 
  <span class="badges float-left"></span>
  <span class="from" style="color:#D2691E">yourusername</span>
  <span class="colon">:</span> 
  <span class="message" style="undefined">message here</span>
</li>
```

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe the following might be what you need.

I added `white-space: nowrap` to the `li` elements to keep the inline child elements on one line.

You then need to add `white-space: normal` to the `.message` span to keep the break-word-wrapping the way you need it.  Remember that `white-space` is inherited, so you need to reset it to `normal` for the inline span.

```css
.messages {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.messages li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.messages li .message {
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<ul class="messages">
  <li>
    <span class="name">wILL</span>
    <span class="message">sakdjfhskdjhfksjahflkjhldkjsakljfhalskdfhqweqweqeqeqweqweqweqweqweqwe</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm !

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is the seriouslyhonkinglongword is being broken *after* it's been pushed onto the next line. [Watch this demonstration closely](http://codepen.io/Alhadis/pen/mJqXXb).

The only quick solution to this would be to add `white-space: pre;` to the container:

```
.messages li .message{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Remember, the whitespace between the two `span` tags still classifies as a space node, so it's being treated as though there were a space character between those two `span` containers.

**FYI:** I had a hard time finding a satisfactory solution to this [issue sometime last year](http://codepen.io/Alhadis/pen/ACbcv), too.

Answer (score 2):

Do not add space in between the spans. That is the key. That allows the spans to be inline.

I hope this helps. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmtv42ks/)

Comment: You are right about the white space between the `span`'s, good point.